# Jquery not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have made a simple program which submit a form when selected an option in the form. This jquery is working fine with every browser except Google Chrome. I don't know why its happening and what should i do but perhaps you can tell me. Here is my jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.option11').click(function (){
         $(this).closest('form').submit();
     });
  });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<form name="input1" action="test.php" method="post">
   <label for="isotopeSorting" class="black-clr">Sort:</label>
   <select id="isotopeSorting" class="span3" name="sort">
      <option name="sort" value='pricelow' class="option11" >By Price (Low to High) &uarr;</option>
      <option name="sort" value='pricehigh' class="option11" >By Price (High to Low) &darr;</option>
      <option name="sort" value='featured' class="option11" >Featured &darr;</option>
      <option name="sort" value='distance' class="option11" >By Distance (Low to High) &uarr;</option>
      <option name="sort" value='newest' class="option11">By popularity &darr;</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Please help me to solve this problem in the chrome as i am an beginner to jquery. Thanks in advance

Comment: Cant's see anything wrong with it, please show your full code including any HTML.

Comment: I have edited my question and added my html code to it

Comment: Did you include the `Jquery` into your HTML?

Comment: How are you including JQuery? Please post your include for the JS files.

Comment: I guess you have forgot to include jQuery in your script.

Comment: `code`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`code`. Thats how included that and one more thing if i include jquery more than one time will it affect my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont attach a click handler to the single options,

rather use the onchange event of the select :

```
 $('form[name="input1"]').on("change","#isotopeSorting",function (){
     $('form[name="input1"]').submit();
 });
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qM9py/1/